# Excel If either of the cells contain text then Display Yes

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is the formula I have so far:

```
 =IF(ISTEXT(AC4&AD4), "Yes", "No")
```

I need it to return Yes if either of the fields contain next, but it only returns yes if both fields contain next. And it should be No if both fields do not contain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `AC4 & AD4` means that you are joining/concatenating the both fields. If one of them is a text, then the result will be a text. That's why you can't obtain the correct result.

Use the formula below. You must use the [OR function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) as it returns `TRUE` when one of the field test TRUE.

```
=IF(OR(ISTEXT(AC4),ISTEXT(AD4)),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: @Egle Please mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)